# "for loop" for changing expression in Python

Tags: python

In general, we use `for` loop to change data over each iteration but in my case I don't want to change data rather want to change `expression`.

See this code below:(if don't understand skip and see the easy version below it)

```
List = []
fixValue = 10
data = 30

if data + fixValue <= 100:
    List.append(data + fixValue)
    
if data - fixValue <= 100:
    List.append(data - fixValue)
    
if data * fixValue <= 100:
    List.append(data * fixValue)
```

If you don't understand the program here is a short way:

```
if expression:
    List.append(expression)
```

In the for loop, I want to change these expressions(`expresssion1` and `expression2`) so that I don't need to write like the first code. (For explaining purpose I put three `if` conditions. But actually, there are more. So I really need a loop which changes expression for each iteration)

I want something like this:

```
for expression in [differentExpresions]:
      if expression:
        List.append(expression)
```

Comment: Where is the `for` loop placed in the code?

Comment: question is extremely unclear, which `expression`

Comment: I used three different `if`. But I want to use for loop to reduce code redundancy. At now I didn't use for loop

Comment: sorry still can't understand what you want

Comment: but plz ask me what didn't you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve the issue would be to directly write the expression in the list. and then use list comprehension for the condition part.

The code can be modified accordingly

```py
fixValue = 10
data = 30

# Simpler version
# list = [data + fixValue, data - fixValue, data * fixValue]
# List = [exp for exp in list if exp <= 100]

# In a single line
List = [exp for exp in [data + fixValue, data - fixValue, data * fixValue] if exp <= 100]
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Actually here we ain't changing the expression at each loop but still it will work for me. Thanks for the answer. You were the first who answered me. Don't know why people are devoting me always.